# Running a method in another class on an object in an arraylist in the first class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the below code which is failing a test harness and I can't figure out why. In my `Hive` class I have an arraylist of bees called cells and a method called `anotherDay` which I want to loop through the arraylist and call each Bees `anotherDay` method on it. The code:

```
ArrayList<Bee> cells = new ArrayList<Bee>();

public void anotherDay(){
    for(int i = 0;i<cells.size(); i++){
    getBee(i).anotherDay();
    }
}
```

My Queen Bee class:

```
public class Queen extends Bee{

    Hive hive = null;   

    public Queen(){
    }

    public Queen(Hive hive){
        this.hive = hive;
        this.type = 1;
        this.age = 11;
        this.health = 3;
    }

    public Bee anotherDay(){
        eat();
        age++;
        if(age%3 == 0){
            hive.addBee(new Egg());
        }
        return this;
    }

    public boolean eat(){
        if(hive.Honey > 2){
            hive.takeHoney(2);
            if(health == 3){
            }else{
                health= health++;
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            health = health -1;
            return false;
        }   
    }

    public int getType(){
        return type;
    }
}
```

Basically when the `anotherDay` method in hive is run I want it to run the `anotherDay` method in the queen class on the queen bee which should increase it's age by 1, lay an egg every 3 days which is added to the arraylist in hive and run the eat method. My test harness is running the `anotherDay` method in hive but failing me as my queen bee is living too long and not laying enough eggs. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What are your expected/actual results?

Comment: What is the amount of honey in the hive?

Comment: the intial amount of honey in the hive is 10 but the test harness removes all the honey and then runs h.anotherDay() 3 times which should reduce the queens health to 0 and kill her but it isn't. My testharness is saying that my queen bee is living too long and laying eggs too often

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code itself. But may I ask how honey is produced in your hive (and how many bees it contains at the start)? Since the queen is 11 years, she lays an egg on the first day. Could it be possible that that one early bee is the cause of the queen surviving too long?